# Postgresql does not detect duplicate name when declaring a parameter or variable with the same name in a function

Tags: postgresql

I use the PG 13.1 version, I do not know if this is a bug or is the default behavior, have the following example

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(
    v1 int,
    v2 float
) RETURNS boolean AS
$$
DECLARE
    v1 int;
    v2 float;
BEGIN
    RAISE INFO 'v1 => %, v2 => %', v1, v2;
    RETURN true;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT test(10,20);
```

Showing

```
INFO:  v1 => <NULL>, v2 => <NULL>

Successfully run. Total query runtime: 79 msec.
1 rows affected.
```

Could someone please explain why Postgres does not detect the "duplicate name" error?

Obviously the result it shows is that of the variables of the DECLARE section

Comment: Yup.  That is how scoping rules work.  I like to prefix the parameters going in with `in_`, `out_`, or perhaps `p_`.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST

Comment: Thank you, I already saw light at the end of the tunnel!

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @Gordon you are running across Postgres's scooping rules. Variables created as parameters have (for lack of a better term) Functional scope while those within the block have (again for lack of a better term) Block scope. When references without qualification, the reference is always to the most resent definition, even within nested blocks.  Try the following; the values assigned are irreverent just notice results and where variable defined:

```
create or replace 
function test(
               v1 int 
             , v2 float
             )
 returns boolean  
language plpgsql 
as $$
declare                 -- an outer block 
    v1 int = 18;
    v2 float = 45.55;
begin
    declare            -- a nested inner block
        v1 text := 'Same name, different type';
        v2 date := now()::date; 
    begin 
        raise info 'Inner Block: v1 => %, v2 => %', v1, v2; 
    end; 

    raise info 'Outer Block: v1 => %, v2 => %', v1, v2;
    raise info 'Function Parameters: v1 => %, v2 => %', test.v1, test.v2; -- Qualified    
    return true;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, very clear, thank you very much!